# PHP HTML DOM parsing of live PHP content?

Tags: php, parsing, dom

So here's something funny.

I'm trying to take the contents of a tweet based on a search, send them to an RTF file and do some other things with them later (art installation; as weird as it sounds). The Twitter stuff works fine — it grabs a random tweet, parses the actual tweet text, and outputs it to a page in `<p>` tags. Good stuff.

I'm using S.C. Chen's excellent [Simple PHP HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net), which I've used before for similar stuff, to parse the resulting page and isolate the `<p>` tags (the only set on the page). For some reason, it's not returning anything.

The Twitter crawler file needs to run remotely for it to work with Twitter's 1.1 API. The thing which makes the RTF file needs to run locally, because it gets sent to a printer via an Automator script and some trickery.

**remote.php**

```
<p><?php        
[stuff that all works fine]
$tweet = $data[$pick];
$print = $tweet['text'];
print $print;    
?></p>
```

**local.php**

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = file_get_html("http://path/to/remote.php");
echo $url;
?>
```

So, like I said, this is outputting with no content. My local Apache `error_log` has no errors (aside from when I hilariously tried to `include()` the remote file, because security is my number three priority).

Any ideas? Does the remote content simply not exist when this request is being made? Is there a way to force the remote content to be available as soon as the local file calls for it, and keep it dynamic and real-time?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by writing the $print value to an html file, then parsing that file instead with the local script.